# Random "Access is Denied" with Copy-Item

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a scheduled task that runs ever 2 minutes to collect data for auditing purposes.  Every so often running the code below it gets an "`Access is Denied`" error.

```
Copy-Item $output $outputfinal -ErrorAction Stop
```

Here are what the 2 variables are set to:

```
$output  = "FileSystem::\\servername\c$\temp\SessionDetails.csv"
$outputfinal  = "FileSystem::\\servername\c$\Dumps\SessionDetails.csv"
```

The last time it happened, I got the error 3 times in a row and then it stopped.  I know it isn't a permissions issue since the code runs fine 99% of the time.  The timing of the errors isn't consistent but when they do happen, we usually get 3 to 7 in a row.  Any ideas what could be randomly causing it.

Comment: I'd put A/V scanning at the top of the suspect list.

Comment: It's probably not a permissions issue, it is most likely a sharing violation... meaning that something else has the file open and locked, and is not allowing PowerShell to copy it. Most likely, as mjolinor suggested, an antivirus application.

Comment: If this is happening intermittently for the same files, I agree that file is being locked open, and if those 3 to 7 times in a row happen over a short time span and then the problem goes away, then mjolinor is almost definitely right that AV scanning is the culprit. However, if the errors persist over a longer time span, you can use Process Explorer from the [Sysinternals suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) to find what process has it locked. Select **Find Handle or DLL** from the **Find** menu, and enter the filename.